# ambari on HDP cluster + ambari-metrics-collector service not start

Tags: metrics, rhel, ambari, hdp

we have some issue with `ambari-metrics-collector` service , ( we have `HDP` cluster version - `2.6.4` with 8 nodes )

ambari metrics collector service can’t start or start of few second then failed

[image]

the details about metrics collector version

```
rpm -qa | grep metrics
ambari-metrics-grafana-2.6.1.0-143.x86_64
ambari-metrics-monitor-2.6.1.0-143.x86_64
ambari-metrics-collector-2.5.0.3-7.x86_64
ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink-2.6.1.0-143.x86_64
```

all machines are `rhel 7.2`

we performed the following steps in order to resolve the problem

1.restart metrics-collector service

```
su - ams -c '/usr/sbin/ambari-metrics-collector --config /etc/ambari-metrics-collector/conf/ stop'
su - ams -c '/usr/sbin/ambari-metrics-collector --config /etc/ambari-metrics-collector/conf/ start'

or

ambari-metrics-collector stop 
ambari-metrics-collector start
```

2.restart ambari-metrics-monitor on all nodes

```
 ambari-metrics-monitor stop
 ambari-metrics-monitor start
```

3.clean the folder `/var/lib/ambari-metrics-collector/hbase-tmp/zookeeper/`

```
mv /var/lib/ambari-metrics-collector/hbase-tmp/zookeeper/zookeeper_0 /tmp/bck/zookeeper/
```

Then restart  metrics-collector service

4.Tuning the metrics-collector  parameters according - https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.1.0/bk_ambari_reference_guide/content/_ams_general_guidelines.html

we update the follwing parameters in ambari

```
metrics_collector_heap_size=1024
hbase_regionserver_heapsize=1024
hbase_master_heapsize=512
hbase_master_xmn_size=128
```

**status for now:** - steps 1-4 doesn’t help

*From the logs we can see the following:*

log file - `ambari-metrics-collector.log`

```
2020-06-25 09:06:14,474 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x172eab71f310002 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
2020-06-25 09:06:14,575 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=master02.sys671.com:61181, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /ams-hbase-unsecure/meta-region-server
```

log file - `hbase-ams-master-master02.sys671.com.log`

```
2020-06-25 09:38:18,799 WARN  [RS:0;master02:51842-SendThread(master02.sys671.com:61181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x172ead5d73a0004 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1125)
2020-06-25 09:38:20,437 INFO  [main-SendThread(master02.sys671.com:61181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server master02.sys671.com/23.2.35.171:61181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-06-25 09:38:20,438 WARN  [main-SendThread(master02.sys671.com:61181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x172ead5d73a0002 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

we also not see that port is listening ( timeline.metrics.service.webapp.address )

```
netstat -tulpn  | grep  6188
```

any advice how to continue from this point ?

we'll appreciate to get any help about this problem

Comment: Does the Ambari Metrics node have enough free resources to take advantage of bumping up the memory settings?     What is the condition of that node?  How many services, how much ram, how much free ram, etc...

Comment: Also error looks like zookeeper connection failed?    You may want to inspect zookeeper log during investigation of the root cause.

Comment: on the machine that metrics-collector is installed we have free memory - 24G , so this isnt the problem

Comment: I looked on the zookeeper server logs and not seen any errors

Comment: any hint how to continue ?

Comment: the other guy posted same on cloudera,  his post had a code snippet that said zk connection issues to ams-hbase... you have to keep following trail to find the culprit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216652/discussion-between-jessica-and-steven-dfheinz).

Comment: How did you end up fixing this issue?